# Looking For Simple Bookmark Package

Tags: bookmarks

Can you recommend, a good bookmark package?

- Yes, emacs standard has bookmarks. Although, hate naming them.
- Just want something small, not uber sophisticated (like bookmark+). (It crashes my setup, at the moment, had to remove it.)
- All I want is a hotkey to mark one location, per file.
- Don't care about saving, between sessions. (Great if just during session.)
- Although, I do have "save last edited place" working now. (Don't know, name of package off top of head.)

Really after, just a remember position (in key), then other hotkey to recall. Yes, plain Emacs bookmark could do this? With a name in macro.

- But, is that the best way?
- Or easiest way?

Comment: Check out the `bm` package.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much! @KaushalModi (*) Some links. [A Visual Bookmarks package for Emacs](http://emacsworld.blogspot.com/2008/09/visual-bookmarks-package-for-emacs.html), and [VisibleBookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisibleBookmarks). In joodland's GitHub repository: bm.

Comment: FWIW: [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) does everything library bm does (and more). There is nothing uber-sophisticated about it: Just because you *can* do more with it does not mean that you must or that you cannot do less. Could you please report details of the problem you encountered ("*crashes my setup*"), by clicking the link `Send Bug Report` after doing `M-x customize-group bookmark-plus`? That might reveal and help fix a Bookmark+ problem, or it might help reveal a pilot error, which could help you. Most people use Bookmark+ in simple ways like what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function to quickly create meaningful bookmarks with a single keypress, without having to think about it:

```
(defun my/quick-save-bookmark ()
  "Save bookmark with name as 'buffer:row:col'"
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-set (format "%s:%s:line %s:column %s"
            (thing-at-point 'symbol)
            (buffer-name)
            (line-number-at-pos)
            (current-column)))
  (message "Bookmarked saved at current position"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-b") 'my/quick-save-bookmark)
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it seems to basically meet your description. I have found it to be very useful and lightweight. I also use `helm` and this to quickly see my bookmarks:

```
(bind-key "<menu>" 'helm-bookmarks)
```

Comment: Yes! Also, **exactly what I am looking for.** Thank you elethan. Although, I should see, if I can get bookmark+ working again. Maybe, the current updates - have repaired it since then, for @Drew

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder how to use the current line's contents as bookmark description, here it is:

```
(defun my/quick-save-bookmark ()
  "Save bookmark with name as 'buffer:row:line-contents'"
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-set (format "%s:%s:%s"
        ;; (thing-at-point 'symbol)
        (buffer-name)
        (line-number-at-pos)
        (string-trim (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
        ;; (current-column)
    ))
  (message "Bookmarked saved at current position"))
(define-key global-map [remap bookmark-set] 'my/quick-save-bookmark)
```

Replaces the usual bookmark-set shortcut `C-x r m`. Works nicely with helm. Also, helm displays bookmarks in chronological order, which automatically assigns sort of a context to them. BTW: you can mark bookmarks in helm using C-SPC and then use C-d to delete them.

Comment: OP: Bookmark+ also has such autonaming of bookmarks (so no prompt for the name when setting a bookmark). See [Autonamed Bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks).